# Question on dual of a problem

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Consider the following primal problem

$$
f=\max_{x}c^{\top}x -{\varepsilon ||x||_2} \quad  \text{s.t.}  \quad Ax\leq b\\
$$
with $\epsilon>0$.
Could you help me to write down the dual of this problem? My suggestion is reported below, but the professor told me that this is the wrong answer. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

$$
f=\min_{y\geq 0} y^\top b\quad \text{s.t.} \quad ||A^\top y -c||_2
\leq \epsilon$$

Comment: Are you sure this is the right question? You are maximising in the primal, but it is not concave unless $\epsilon$ is negative.

Comment: I think I wrote a $+$, but there should be a $-$ in the primal. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Hint: Try converting the primal to a minimization problem. Then find a finite inf of the Lagrangian.

Comment: Could you give some more details? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to tell your 'professor' to find a new job.

The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,y)=c^{\top}x -{\varepsilon ||x||_2} + y^T(b-Ax)$$

The primal is $\max_x \min_{y \geq 0} L(x,y)$ and the dual is $\min_{y \geq 0} \max_x L(x,y)$. Now:
\begin{align}
\max_x L(x,y) &= \max_x \left\{ b^Ty - (A^Ty-c)^Tx-{\varepsilon ||x||_2} \right\} \\
&= \begin{cases} b^Ty & \text{if } ||A^Ty-c||_2 \leq \varepsilon \\ \infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{align}
Therefore, the dual is $\min_{y \geq 0} \left\{ b^Ty : ||A^Ty-c||_2 \leq \varepsilon\right\}$.